# pygame strange behavior on key pressings

Tags: python, pygame

I am kind of new to pygame module.

I am keeping track of the key pressings from the terminal via PyCharm IDE.

To clearness, I am adding screenshot of the workspace of mine below.

[image]

**Now, the problem is, I found out that, If I am pressing and holding `DOWN` and `UP` keys at the same time, the system can detect `RIGHT` key pressings, however ignorant to `LEFT` key pressings.**

**Same thing is valid for holding `W` and `S` keys together and sensing `T` key but not sensing `E` or `Q` keys.**

**`RIGHT` & `LEFT` being hold, senses `DOWN` does not sense `UP`**

I am adding a fully ready to run code(except you need pygame module installed) for ones who might want to try on their computer.

```
import pygame
#import time

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

#carImg = pygame.image.load('raceCar.png')


# def drawCar(x, y):
#    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x, y))


x = display_width * 0.45
y = display_height * 0.6
dx = 0
dy = 0

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("MY GAME")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

crashed = False
Quit = False

i = 0

while not crashed and not Quit:



    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        #     Quit = True
        #
        # elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        #
        #     if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        #         dy += 5
        #     elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        #         dy += -5
        #     elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        #         dx += 5
        #     elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        #         dx += -5
        #
        # elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        #
        #     if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        #         dy += -5
        #     elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        #         dy += 5
        #     elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        #         dx += -5
        #     elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        #         dx += 5
        #
        # elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        #     Quit = True

        i += 1
        print(i, event)

    # x = (x + 1) % display_width
    # y = (y - 1) % display_height
    x += dx
    y += dy
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    x = x if x <= display_width else -163
    x = x if x+163 >= 0 else display_width
    y = y if y <= display_height else -244
    y = y if y + 244 >= 0 else display_height
    # drawCar(x, y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Note that, I have commented out unnecessary parts in order to make it ready to run for anyone easily.

Comment: You can [check here](http://keyboardchecker.com/) whether pygame or your keyboard is to blame. Mine seems to support up to 6 simultaneous key presses.

Comment: @Junuxx hmm, thanks for the advice, it looks like it is related with my keyboard. Have any idea why a keyboard might be supporting multiple key pressings in according to which keys are pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely the result of hardware limitations. It's called [keyboard ghosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29) and happens to most cheap commercial keyboards

Comment: Actually, if it were like "my keyboard is supporting only up to 3 key pressings at the same instant", I would understand it. However, what makes me confusing is why I can press 4 5 6 keys at the same time but cannot press 3 keys if I try some other combination of keys.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's the way your code is handling key-presses.  It's better to use the `pygame.key.get_pressed()`, which returns a dictionary of the current state of all keys pressed at that instant. But the presented code (the commented out section) does not seem to have any issues that would cause this.

Below is some example code that demonstrates handling multiple key-presses.  You can also use it to ensure your keyboard handles multiple presses correctly.  I would expect every keyboard can handle a minimum of 3 simultaneous key-presses, since otherwise <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> would be impossible.

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT   =  50
WINDOW_SURFACE  = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE
DARK_BLUE     = (   3,   5,  54)
WHIPPED_CREAM = ( 251, 252, 214 )

### initialisation
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), WINDOW_SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Multi Keys Test")

# We need to write some stuff
default_font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)

### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

    # Make a string of which arrow-keys are pressed
    # EDIT: Removing the loop, as it seems to be causing some minor confusion  
    currently_pressed = ""
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if ( keys[ pygame.K_UP ] ):
        currently_pressed += "up "
    if ( keys[ pygame.K_DOWN ] ):
        currently_pressed += "down "
    if ( keys[ pygame.K_LEFT ] ):
        currently_pressed += "left "
    if ( keys[ pygame.K_RIGHT ] ):
        currently_pressed += "right "
    keys_text = default_font.render( currently_pressed, True, WHIPPED_CREAM )

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    window.fill( DARK_BLUE )
    window.blit( keys_text, ( 10, 10 ) )
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

pygame.quit()
```

For what it's worth, I can get it to show "left right up down" all together.

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer, however I suspect it is related to my keyboard instead of pygame or the code. Please have a look at this if you are interested or may know something about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60709877/why-my-keyboard-is-key-selective-in-multi-key-pressings

Comment: " check_key, key_name = check_key " is this a valid assignment?

Comment: @muyustan - Yes it's valid.  `check_key` is iterating over a set of `[ keycode, "name" ]` lists.  So at assignment time, it amounts to `a,b = [ sometthing, something ]`, which is obviously valid python syntax.

Comment: it looks like something like `a,b = a`

Comment: Well yes, but that `= a` is assigning a list of two elements.  In the first iteration, `[ pygame.K_UP,   "up" ]`.   Imagine it said:  `for fruit in ( 'apple', 'orange', 'pair' )`, each iteration `fruit` is assigned to a string.  Now imagine it's `for fruit in ( [ 'apple', 3.5], ['orange',2.95], ['pear', 1.20] )`.  Each iteration, `fruit` is a list of `[ <fruit-name-string>, <fruit-cost-float>]`.  If the code then said: `name,cost = fruit`, it would be valid.  That is what's happening here.

Comment: either I cannot get it or you did a typo in your answer and are not looking to the right place now. I am talking about this line, `check_key, key_name = check_key`. How something(check_key) comma another thing is equal to that same thing.

Comment: either way, I appreciate your answer, and it gave me an idea about how I can handle pressed keys in a different way. However, in the scope of this question, I guess it is not about the code but about my keyboard.

Comment: I removed the loop.  I hope it is easier to understand now.  FWIW: It was not a typo, it's was 100% correct, and tested before posting.  Please try this code:   `fruit = [ 'apple', 2.90 ]`   `fruit, cost = fruit` `print( fruit, cost )`

Comment: I now tried it myself, I guess the point I missed was that it is overwriting variable `check_key`. Got it now

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can solve your problem but its worth a shot. I was having a similar issue where some of my keys would not be detected if they were pressed at the same time. I changed all the elif and else statements in my code to if statements which fixed the problem. Logically, it makes sense since you are telling the computer that you only want to check if the key is pressed ONLY IF (which is what elif means) the if statement above is not true.

Your code will look something like this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():

     if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == 
     pygame.K_ESCAPE:
         Quit = True
    
     if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

         if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
             dy += 5
         if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
             dy += -5
         if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
             dx += 5
         if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
             dx += -5
    
     if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    
         if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
             dy += -5
         if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
             dy += 5
         if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
             dx += -5
         if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
             dx += 5

         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Quit = True
```

However, it may need some other adjustments. For instance, you might need to change the "if" in the string that checks for pygame.KEYUP to an "elif." Hope this helps.

edit: just realized this post is from a while ago, oh well.....